# Ambiguous Column Name in SQlite3 when attempting do to a select statement with a join clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

It seems like sqlite3 needs additional information in terms of specifying where you want to extract certain columns from when joining two tables. Somehow, when I try to do a select statement with a join clause, the query returns:

```
Error: ambiguous column name: name
```

even though I have specified in my statement where I want the 'name' column to be retrieved from, in this case from table t1:

```
select name from t1 join t2 on t1.name = t2.name where beer = 'Alesmith Decadence' and nickname = 'SUP';
```

So does sqlite3 not understand this format or something? Or is more information needed for sqlite3 to understand this query.

Comment: select t.name or t2.name... It's good SQL coding practice to always qualify all columns (when several tables are involved.)

Comment: right, but I mean in this case I specified where I wanted to retrieve the column from on the from clause no?

Comment: Your FROM has two tables, each with a column `name`. You have to specify which one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a query, you should learn to qualify *all* columns names -- with convenient table aliases.  It is unclear what the right aliases are, but something like this:

```
select t1.name
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.name = t2.name
where t2.beer = 'Alesmith Decadence' and t2.nickname = 'SUP';
```

Then it is clear to you, to everyone else, AND to the SQL parser exactly which columns you are referring to.

Note:  You haven't shown sample data or shown the table definitions, so that above may not work because the table aliases may not be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select t1.name
from t1 join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where beer = 'Alesmith Decadence' and nickname = 'SUP';
```